# PHP Special Operators

Tags: php, operators

I came across a group of special operators however have no idea what they do, when you would use them, etc. I am unsure if there are more special operators. Can someone please tell me what they do, when I would use them and also give examples as I have just learning coding and PHP.

```
Special Operators
+=, *=, .=
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're shortcuts, basically

```
$var = $var + 1         same as $var += 1;       (add 1 to var)
$var = $var * 2;        same as $var *= 2;       (multiple var by two)
$var = $var . 'blah';   same as $var .= 'blah';  (append 'blah' to var)
```

Answer (score 1):

`+=` is adding another number onto your variable

```
$blah += 5; // $blah gets 5 added to it
```

`*=`  is multiplying another number onto your variable

```
$blah += 5; // $blah gets multiplied by 5
```

`.=` is a concatenation operator

```
$blah .= " Another string"; // $blah gets " Another string" added onto the end of it (or gets converted into a string if it isn't already one
```

Answer (score 1):

They're short-cuts for other things:

```
$x = 1;
$x += 1; // this is the same as $x = $x + 1; $x is now 2.

$y = 3;
$y *= 4; // this is the same as $y = $y * 4; $y is now 12.

$s = "hello"
$s .= " world"; // this is the same as $s = $s . " world"
                // i.e., string concatenation; 
                // $s is now "hello world"
```

Comment: Thanks. That helps clarify the portion of code at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706931/php-array-walk-recursive. However I am having a hard type following the flow of the logic. I don't know why null is being applied and what is the purpose of the parentKey. As you scroll down the code, it reads output .= which I take it to mean $output = $output . $something but what is that something?

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey: Ah! I see what you mean. What's happening there is that the function outputAnswers is being called, and the output of that function is being apended to $output. So it's exactly the same as $x = outputAnswers($value, $currentKey); followed by $output .= $x; hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Those are compound assignment operators.

In laymen's terms, they mean the following:

```
$a += $b <=> $a = $a + $b
$a *= $b <=> $a = $a * $b
$a .= $b <=> $a = $a . $b
```

However, that's not necessarily how they are implemented. [Eric Lippert](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/03/29/compound-assignment-part-one.aspx) has a blog entry concerning similar operators in the C# language, you might get an idea of what problems one could have implementing such operators.

Answer (score 0):

`+=` is shorthand for addition. Instead of writing `$i = $i + $j` you can write `$i += $j`. It adds the value of `$j` to `$i`.

Ditto for `*=`, except it's multiplication.

`.=` is for string concatenation, so `$str1 .= $str2` is the same as `$str1 = $str1 . $str2`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably best to give an example. These two bits of code do the same thing:

```
$a = 2
$a = $a + 2
```

and

```
$a = 2
$a += 2
```